# How to cycle through a list of text using a button on javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, list, html5-canvas

This is my 1st question on stackoverflow. I'm still a bit new to javascript and I'm trying to make a simple interactive story. 
There is a list of sentences that I want to go through. Each sentence is to be displayed on the canvas and a button would move to the next sentence. I've tried using a few different solutions but the canvas isn't changing when I press the Next button. 
I have called the increment function (plusOne) during the code to test if the function actually works and it does. It seems the problem is in relation to the button.
Here's the canvas and button:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height = "320"></canvas>
<button onclick = "plusOne()">Next</button>
```

Here's the function and the variables

```
const plusOne = () =>{
lineMarker++;
}

//making a list of words and getting font
var myLines = ["Hello and welcome",
            "How are you doing?",
            "I'm doing quite well thank you"]

var lineMarker = 0;
```

I called the plusOne() function 4 times just to check that the canvas displayed the value of lineMarker as 4, which it did!
And here are the lines of code that draw to the canvas:

```
ctx.fillText(myLines[lineMarker%3], 8, 250);
ctx.fillText(("Line number is: "+lineMarker.toString()), 10,80);
```

The canvas displays the value of lineMarker and the sentence that's in the list.
However, the button is not incrementing the value and I have tried making a separate button in javascript but that also failed to work.
I've held off on asking questions for a long time, for fear that I might be missing something completely obvious which I'll figure out sooner or later, but forums and tutorials have convinced me to ask around, so here I am!
Anyone know how to sort this out?

Comment: check the answer below. Is this what you are looking for and if so do you understand what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close just a few small changes.

Firstly, you needed to update the canvas within the `plusOne` function.

You also needed to clear the canvas from the previous `fillText`

```js
var lineMarker = 0;

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

const plusOne = () => {

  lineMarker++;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.fillText(myLines[lineMarker % 3], 8, 250);
  ctx.fillText(("Line number is: " + lineMarker.toString()), 10, 80);
}

//making a list of words and getting font
var myLines = ["Hello and welcome",
  "How are you doing?",
  "I'm doing quite well thank you"
];

ctx.fillText(myLines[lineMarker % 3], 8, 250);
ctx.fillText(("Line number is: " + lineMarker.toString()), 10, 80);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height = "320"></canvas>
<button onclick = "plusOne()">Next</button>
```

Comment: Working perfectly now! Thank you very much!